# Prefer some alternatives in regex

Tags: .net, regex

I have this regex

```
("[^"]*")|('[^']*')|([^<>]+)
```

When handed this input string

```
<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">
```

I would like it to match`RGB`. However, since the last alternative results in a longer string, it doesn't.

What I ideally want is this:

1. if there is a double-quoted substring, match it, including the double quotes.
2. otherwise, if there is a single-quoted substring, match it, including the single quotes.
3. otherwise, if there is a string surrounded by angle brackets, match it, not including the angle brackets.

Can this logic be done in a single regex?

Comment: Maybe you should be using an XML parser instead.

Comment: You could just use more than one regex

Comment: You can probably do this with negative look-arounds, but why not nest it (test for the quoted examples, and if not, check for the `<>`) (You are missing the enclosing <> in the last search, so it will match everything in a line...)

Comment: @Tim and Alan: I'm trying to make the smallest possible change to existing software ([Resource Refactoring Tool](http://resourcerefactor.codeplex.com/)) to get it to behave better (be able to match a single attribute in ASPX code instead of the whole line). I don't want to completely rewrite the tool.

Comment: @beroe: Can you explain what you mean by "nest it"?  -- And apparently, skipping the enclosing <> was intentional. It will match everything inside a single tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var strings = new[]
        {"<telerik:RadTab Text=\"RGB\">", "<telerik:RadTab Text=RGB>", "<telerik:RadTab Text='RGB'>"};
    var r = new Regex("<([^<\"']+[^>\"']+)>|(\"[^\"]*\")|('[^']*')");
    foreach (var s1 in strings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s1);
        var match = r.Match(s1);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Almost perfect! Except that, for stupid reasons, the surrounding < and > should NOT have been part of the match. :( I see that they're not part of the subgroup, so perhaps that will be good enough ... I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: The given code seems to be stupid in other ways... sigh. I'll accept your answer since it answers what I asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution to this problem is to use lookahead assertions:

```
(?=("[^"]*"))|(?=('[^']*'))|(?=<([^<>]+)>)
```

Let's décompose the regex to get a better view:

```
(?=             # zero-width assertion, look ahead if there is ...
    ("[^"]*")   # a double quoted string, group it in group number 1
)               # end of lookahead
|               # or
(?=             # zero-width assertion, look ahead if there is ...
('[^']*')       # a single quoted string, group it in group number 2
)               # end of lookahead
|               # or
(?=             # zero-width assertion, look ahead if there is ...
<([^<>]+)>      # match anything except <> between <> one or more times and group it in group number 3
)               # end of lookahead
```

You might think `what in the world is he doing?`, no problem I will explain further why your regex fail.

We have the following string `<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">`:

```
<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">
^ the regex engine starts here
since there is no match with ("[^"]*")|('[^']*')|([^<>]+)
it will look further !

<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">
 ^ the regex engine will now take a look here
it will check if there is "[^"]*", well obviously there isn't
now since there is an alternation, the regex engine will
check if there is '[^']*', meh same thing
it will now check if there is [^<>]+, but hey it matches !

So your regex engine will "eat" it like so
<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ and match this, by eating I mean it's advancing
Now the regex engine is at this point
<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">
                          ^ and obviously, there is no match
The problem is, you want it to "step" back to match "RGB"
The regex engine won't go back for you :(
```

That's why we use zero-width assertions with groups, it won't eat (won't advance) and if you use a group inside the lookahead you still get your matched group.

```
<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">
^ So when it comes here, it will match it with (?=<([^<>]+)>)
but it won't eat the whole matched string
Now obviously, the regex needs to continue to look for other matches
So it comes here:
<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">
 ^ no match
<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">
  ^ no match
.....
until
<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">
                     ^ hey there is a match using (?=("[^"]*"))
it will then advance further
<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB">
                      ^ no match
.... until it reaches the end
```

Of course, if you had a string like `<telerik:RadTab Text="RGB'lol'">` it would still match `'lol'` in the double quoted value and put it in group number 2.

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/gK9bV4)</kbd>
                                                                                                                                                       
<sub><sub><sub>*Regex rocks !!!*</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you, lookahead seems like a very useful feature, and you've explained it beautifully.  I won't be using it for this case though because the code was stupid in another way. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Consider the following Regular Expression...

```
(\".*?\"|\'.*?\'|(?<=\<).*?(?=\>))
```